# Codeigniter: How can I successfully insert a referenced ID into another table using insert_id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables

visits - id | visit_date | patient_id | notes | staff_id

visits_procedures - id | visit_id | procedure_id | quantity

The visits_procedures table is meant to track the number of procedures performed during a visit. If I insert data into the visits table, it is works fine. However, when I insert data into the visits_procedures table, it does not work as expected. For instance, if the last visit.id = 3, it is expected that when I insert data into the visits_procedures table the value of visits_procedures.visit_id should be 3 as well. However, when I submit data to the visits_procedures table, it gives the visits_procedures.visit_id as 4 because a row is added to the visits table with the primary key auto incremented and other columns given value zero.

Could you please help me come up with a solution that will work as expected. Here is my code.

MY_Model

```
public function insert($data) {

        $this->db->insert($table_name, $data);

        return $this->db->insert_id();

    }
```

VisitProcedures controller

```
function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model(array('admin/vprocedure'));

        $this->load->model(array('admin/procedure'));

        $this->load->model(array('admin/visit'));
}

public function create() {

        if ($this->input->post('procedure_id')) {

            $visit_id = $this->visit->insert($data);

            $data['visit_id'] = $visit_id;

            $data['procedure_id'] = $this->input->post('procedure_id');

            $data['quantity'] = $this->input->post('quantity');

                 $this->vprocedure->insert($data);

                 redirect('/admin/visit-procedures', 'refresh');

        }

        $procedures = $this->procedure->get_all();

        $data['procedures'] = $procedures;

            .
            .//load view code
            .
}
```

Visit_model

```
class Visit extends MY_Model {

    public function __construct() {  

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insertar($data) {

        $this->db->insert('visits', $data);

        $latest_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        return $latest_id;

    }
}
```

Comment: This line is inserting the extra datarow `$visit_id = $this->visit->insert($data);`  I would think it just needs to be `$visit_id = $this->visit->id;`  But without seeing anything else i can't be sure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, makes sense about the extra row. That line `$visit_id = $this->visit->insert($data);` was meant to get the value of the last inserted id that is being returned insert function in the visit_model (I have edited the question to include the visit_model). However, from what you've pointed out, that line is doing an insertion. How do I just get the last inserted id alone? Your help will be appreciated. By the way, the suggestion doesn't work, the id is not defined.

Comment: Is the ID of the visit in your url?  If not, it is very easy to add to it through routing.  And is very easy to get from the url.

Comment: Try removing the insert method from the MY_Model file. You have a lot of redundancy going on here. If you want to specify a dynamic table to insert, use it as an additional parameter in the method call instead. $this->model->insert('visits', $data).

Comment: @Dominofoe The visit.id appears on the url when one edits or views a record which are displayed in a datatable.  Below are my routes `$route['admin/visits'] = 'admin/visits'; `

`$route['admin/visits/create'] = 'admin/visits/create';`

`$route['admin/visits/edit/(:any)'] = 'admin/visits/edit/$1';`

`$route['admin/visits/delete/(:any)'] = 'admin/visits/delete/$1';`

`$route['admin/visits/view/(:any)'] = 'admin/visits/view/$1';`

Comment: @Joe The insert method in MY_Model is being used by other models, they extend it. The one in the visit model must be the redundant one. I actually defined it in the visit model to test if the last inserted id was being returned. I had renamed it to something else in my code but seems I didn't do that when I added it in the question. I have edited it. The intent was to get help on how I can pass the value of what is being returned ($latest_id) to the visitProcedures controller. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: I just created a test controller and model (without extending anything) using your exact database setup. It worked exactly as it's supposed to. So I wonder... and this is a completely shot in the dark... But what if you rename the array you're passing to the vprocedure model instead of using $data (which I assume exists and comes from somewhere, because you've passed it to the visit model). Otherwise, I'm at a loss. I can't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Interesting finding @Joe. I have tried your idea by not extending the visit model but had to copy some methods from MY_Model into it, that way it works. I have also found a work around that doesn't use insert_id: `public function get_latest_id(){`

       `$this->db->select_max('id');`

        `$result= $this->db->get('visits')->row_array();`

        `return $result['id'];`
   ` } `  Thank you for taking time to reproduce and helping me come up with a solution, I truly appreciate :) .

Comment: Well, sorry it wasn't using the setup you wanted, but glad you found a way to make it happen.

Comment: @Dominofoe Thanks for your help earlier, my issue is now resolved.